# Polaroids / columns not displaying correctly in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using a polaroid effect combined with a masonry effect in order to build a portfolio page.  However, while everything is visually correct in internet explorer, and chrome, in firefox the polaroids are not displaying correctly, especially when they switch columns.

https://jsfiddle.net/chris2001/atu52840/

```
/*portfolio */

#projects {
line-height: 0;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 0px;
-moz-column-gap: 0px;
-moz-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 0px;
}

#projects img {
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
}

#projects a {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
background: yellow;
 display: inline;
float: left;
margin: 0 10px 10px;
padding: 10px 10px 35px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
z-index:0;
    position:relative;

   }

 #projects a:after {
color: #333;
font-size: 20px;
content: attr(title);
position: relative;
top:15px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using CSS that is still in candidate status. The only version of IE that works with properties like column-count are IE10+. I would recommend against using candidate properties. Instead, I would recommend you lay this out using flexbox instead. You can find a really good tutorial here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/